# System.JSONException: For input string

Tags: apex, rest-api, integration, apexrest, deserialize

When ever i click on Upload Intent then works perfectly and i get response but when i click on status i get this json error, 
This is my VF,

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!upload}" value="Upload Intent"  reRender="output" id="upload" />   
<apex:commandButton action="{!Train}" value="Train Dataset" reRender="output1" id="train" /> 
<apex:outputText style="top: 50px;margin-left: 55px;font-size: x-large;" rendered="true" id="output" value="{!probability }"></apex:outputText>
<apex:outputText style="top: 50px;margin-left: 55px;font-size: x-large;" rendered="true" id="output1" value="{!modelid}"></apex:outputText>
```

This is my Class.

```
public void Train() {
 string name = 'Weather Intent Model';
 tokenkey = eaccess.getAccessToken();
 modelid= eaccess.getstatus(name, tokenkey, datasetid);
 }
```

eaccess Class

```
 public static statusresponse getstatus(string name ,string token,integer datasetid){
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req .setMethod( 'POST');
        req .setEndpoint('https://api.einstein.ai/v2/language/train');
        req .setHeader( 'Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token );
        req .setHeader( 'Cache-Control', 'no-cache' );
        req .setHeader( 'Content-Type', HttpFormBuilder.GetContentType() );

        req.setTimeout( 120000 );
        system.debug( 'name '+ name+ ' datasetId  '+ datasetId );
        String mutipartFormData = '';
        mutipartFormData += HttpFormBuilder.WriteBoundary();
        mutipartFormData += HttpFormBuilder.WriteBodyParameter( 'name', name );
        mutipartFormData += HttpFormBuilder.WriteBoundary();
        mutipartFormData += HttpFormBuilder.WriteBodyParameter( 'datasetId',String.valueOf(datasetId ) );
        mutipartFormData += HttpFormBuilder.WriteBoundary( NULL );

        Blob formBlob = EncodingUtil.base64Decode( mutipartFormData );

        req.setBodyAsBlob( formBlob );

        Http http = new Http();
        system.debug( formBlob );
        HTTPResponse response= http.send( req);
        system.debug(response.getBody());

                statusresponse statusres= (statusresponse ) System.JSON.deserialize(response.getBody(), statusresponse .class);

         statusresponse  model= statusres;
         getmodeldetails(token,model);
        return model;

    }
```

I GET ERROR FROM THIS LINE

```
statusresponse statusres= (statusresponse ) System.JSON.deserialize(response.getBody(), statusresponse .class);
```

My Response Class

```
public class statusresponse{
    public Integer datasetId;   //1023017
    public Integer datasetVersionId;    //0
    public String name; //Weather Intent Model
    public String status;   //QUEUED
    public Integer progress;    //0
    public String createdAt;    //2017-11-23T18:16:07.000+0000
    public String updatedAt;    //2017-11-23T18:16:07.000+0000
    public Integer learningRate;    //0
    public Integer epochs;  //0
    public Integer queuePosition;   //1
    public String objects;   //training
    public String modelId;  //O6OQTXTPN4GFNHO4WDY5VKNGKY
    public cls_trainParams trainParams;
    public cls_trainStats trainStats;
    public String modelType;    //text-intent
    class cls_trainParams {
    }
    class cls_trainStats {
    }
    public static statusresponse parse(String json){
        return (statusresponse) System.JSON.deserialize(json, statusresponse.class);
    }


}
```

Debug log Error

```
FATAL_ERROR System.JSONException: For input string: "0.0" at [line:1, column:189]
 FATAL_ERROR Class.System.JSON.deserialize: line 15, column 1
 FATAL_ERROR Class.einsteinaccess.getstatus: line 144, column 1
 FATAL_ERROR Class.einsteinsentiment.Train: line 44, column 1
```

This is my Json:

```
{"datasetId":1022045,"datasetVersionId":0,"name":"Weather Intent Model","status":"QUEUED","progress":0,"createdAt":"2017-11-23T20:11:55.000+0000","updatedAt":"2017-11-23T20:11:55.000+0000","learningRate":0.0,"epochs":0,"queuePosition":1,"object":"training","modelId":"TGQHXXMOK363IYQ6OXJC6ENMME","trainParams":null,"trainStats":null,"modelType":"text-intent"}
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to put a Decimal value in to an Integer. What happens if you change your class to use Decimal values instead?

Comment: Its integer, if its a decimal then it would have returned .0 in all the places.

Comment: How do we know the data type? You didn't actually share your JSON with us. Point is, the parser expected type X, but the JSON has type Y.

Comment: Uploaded my JSON response too

Comment: Even i tested 30+ times in all the way its because of the `statusresponse statusres= (statusresponse ) System.JSON.deserialize(response.getBody(), statusresponse .class);`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
public Integer learningRate; //0
```

In your JSON, it appears as a Decimal value. Change the code as follows:

```
public Decimal learningRate; //0.0
```

Comment: I have question how did u know it was a decimal? because i have many responses to work on

Comment: @kishore consider using [json2apex](http://json2apex.herokuapp.com/) to help you out. As a general case, JSON supports only about six types. Integer, decimal, Boolean, date, date time, and string (plus arrays and objects). Check out the JSON specs online to learn more.