# JSON.deserialize throw exception

Tags: json, deserialize

I am trying to deserialize a string into a inner class. the I can transform that class into the real salesforce class, because the variables names are not the same ones than the real class. But when I try to deserialize the string. an error is thrown with no explanation.

```
for (Map<String, Object> record : recordListMap){
            String serialisedRecord = JSON.serialize(record); //to see in logs what a json looks like
            system.debug(serialisedRecord);
            try {
                Json2Apex productRequestContainer = (Json2Apex)JSON.deserialize(serialisedRecord, Json2Apex.class);
                system.debug(productRequestContainer);
            } catch(JSONException e) {
                System.debug('The following exception has occurred: ' + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
```

I used https://www.adminbooster.com/tool/json2apex to transform my Json into an Inner class that I can use.

the Json looks like this:

```
{
  "GO_Frankie": true,
  "DATE_REQUIRED": "2022-03-23",
  "QTY_total_to_buy": 4,
  "SOL_CODE": "100079493",
  "MODEL": "LOC L515H025\n",
  "MANUFACTURER": "no",
  "Sub_Section_2": "L5-15",
  "Section": "CABLE",
  "Department": "Audio",
  "REF_NO": "02-AUD-CAB-L515-001",
  "Record_ID": 1323
}
```

and the inner class:

```
public class Json2Apex{
    public boolean GO_Frankie;
    public String DATE_REQUIRED;
    public Integer QTY_total_to_buy;
    public String SOL_CODE;
    public String MODEL;
    
    public String MANUFACTURER;
    public String Sub_Section_2;
    public String Section;
    public String Department;
    public String REF_NO;
    public Integer Record_ID;
}
```

I dont have any errors in my code, si I really don't see the problem. and the error in the logs give me no information at all.
[image]

Comment: Update: I changed the type of QTY_total_to_buy from integer to String, It works. But I still don't know why the Record_ID varaible doesn't make an error too

Comment: What makes you think that there was something wrong with QTY_total_to_buy being an Integer? According to the JSON you present, it clearly isn't a String. What makes you think that Record_ID should be causing errors? Could you please paste into your question,  what your System debug says on `serialisedRecord`?

Comment: the USER_DEBUG says the problem is with string "4.0", and the only field with that value is  QTY_total_to_buy. Also, like I said, changing the type to a string worked, but I just don't know why it is the only field causing this error, since there are other Integer-type field

Comment: Have a look at the output of `system.debug(serialisedRecord);` and I suspect you find your JSON looks slightly different from what you thought it would. [JSON knows numbers](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259.txt), the integer 4 is a number and your error message is referring to a string (which represents a decimal, not an integer anyway).

Comment: here is the exact system.debug(serialisedRecord): 14:57:41:701 USER_DEBUG [53]|DEBUG|{"GO_Frankie":true,"DATE_REQUIRED":"2022-03-23","QTY_total_to_buy":4.0,"SOL_CODE":"100079493","MODEL":"LOC L515H025\n","MANUFACTURER":"none","Sub_Section_2":"L5-15","Section":"CABLE","Department":"Audio","REF_NO":"02-AUD-CAB-L515-001","Record_ID":1323}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have found a bug of that adminbooster tool, because `4.0` (as can be read from the log cited in your comment, not from your original question) is a Decimal or Double, not an Integer. From the perspective of Apex, the difference between Decimal and Integer is a difference of external representation, not value. Therefore `4` appears to it as a very different animal. So much regarding why there is an exception for QTY_total_to_buy, but not for Record_ID.

A StackExchange discussion along similar lines can be found [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/199917/system-jsonexception-for-input-string).

I suggest to choose Decimal (or Double) in your inner class, not String. I assume "QTY" to mean "Quantity". If you use String, you might want to convert later anyway, e.g. to calculate totals, make comparisons in reporting etc.

As for the error talking of "input string" and such, I have to thank you, because I was mislead myself. This appears to be a bug of Apex. Possible explanation: Apex JSON deserialization accepts Strings for numbers; because the conversion from `4.0` to Integer fails, it attempts to first convert `4.0` to `"4.0"` and convert this to the Integer; after this fails too, the error message only mentions the String. At least that's how I'd explain the wrongly stated type.